# É possível SEO com site que contém apenas Imagens?

Tags: seo

Não entendo muito de **SEO** e **inserção do site em buscadores**.

Contenho um site, porém **só utilizo imagem** nele, o máximo de texto que eu coloco é o telefone e endereço.

> - O que vocês acham sobre isto de acordo com o **SEO** e **inserção do site** em **Buscadores**?

Comment: Resposta curta: sim dá, mas... seria melhor textos, links e outras coisas, que tenham uma grande quantidade de conteudos (e tipos) diferentes, porque se só tem imagens, não haverá textos sobre sua marca, seu conteudo, o que tem no seu site (buscadores não leem imagens =D)

Comment: Na verdade, é possível sim. Mas, você terá que fazer o uso dos atributos HTML, title e alt. Não esquecendo, também, do atributo longdesc, usado para acessibilidade. Mas, é claro que existem inúmeros fatores de posicionamento de uma página web, nas [primeiras posições do Google](https://www.rhbinformatica.com.br/dicas/como-aparecer-gratuitamente-na-primeira-pagina-do-google). Como a [performance](https://www.rhbinformatica.com.br/dicas/como-melhorar-a-performance-e-otimizar-o-seu-site-wordpress), [estratégia SEO](https://www.rhbinformatica.com.br/dicas/como-realizar-uma-estrategia-seo-eficaz-pa

Answer (score 0):

SEO é algo delicado que requer tempo e dedicação, é injusto dizer que somente imagens irá melhorar sua pontuação SEO já que quanto melhor sua pontuação melhor será sua classificação SEO. Em meio a tantos critérios para definir um site bem posicionado utilizar apenas imagens seria o mesmo que competir sem recursos, com isso, recomendo utilizar tanto imagens como também textos.

Answer (score 0):

Como já citado, SEO é um conteúdo muito amplo para conseguirmos chegar aqui e te passar uma fórmula

Já que você só utiliza imagens, recomendo abusar das **metatags**, preencha o maior número possível de informações para que o buscador consiga entender o seu site e assim poder recomendar ele mais facilmente.

Answer (score 0):

Melhorando ainda mais a resposta, normalmente as imagens tem esse formato:

```
<img src="nome-da-imagem.jpg" width="300" height="150">
```

O exemplo acima, seria o básico. Na verdade, o ideal seria você usar dessa forma:

```
<img src="nome-da-imagem.jpg"> width="300" height="150" alt="Nome da Imagem" title="Nome da Imagem" longdesc="Esta imagem é sobre o assunto tal, onde podemos ver que o pôr-do-sol">
```

Com o atributo alt, você informa o buscador sobre o que se trata a imagem. Lembrando que o nome da mesma, não pode ser DSC001.jpg. O src da imagem tem que ser descritivo, mesmo.

Dessa forma, terá uma associação com o alt e title da mesma. O longdesc é como se fosse o texto do "artigo", facilitando o uso de pessoas que necessitam de algum tipo de accessibilidade para usar páginas web.

Caso, seu site seja em WordPress, existem vários plugins que permitem isso. Um que eu indico, é o WP Accessibility. A vantagem de uso é que boa parte dos sites, não usa. Portanto, você consegue melhorar facilmente, o seu posicionamento nos mecanismos de buscas.

Mas, seguindo outras regras de performance e sinais sociais para que a sua página web, possa estar em uma boa posição.

Comment: Cara evite duas respostas para a mesma pergunta, edite sua resposta anterior com essas informações ou delete a anterior que está incompleta.